# Expected number of steps till getting given sum of dice rolls

Tags: probability, markov-chains, expected-value, generating-functions, conditional-expectation

You are throwing a fair, $6$-sided dice till $N = 7$ most recent rolls sum up to $s = 28$. Then, the game ends.

What is the expected number of throws required to end the game?

I have solved the problem numerically resolving system of equations of the expected values, conditioned by previous $N-1$ states and obtained expected number of throws $= 24.7213325$.

However, I am interested in other approaches to solve the problem, perhaps via generating functions, smartly designed absorbed Markov chains?

Comment: Did you compute the probability that 7 rolls sum up to exactly 28? That doesn't directly answer your question but seems useful as a first step for an exact solution.

Comment: @quarague That probability is $p=0.065468536$. However, I don't see how to get an exact solution from that. Assuming the sums are independent, we'd have a geometric variable, and the mean time would be $6+1/p=21.27451301$ But this is a very crude approximation.